# How to send response after reading embedded document data from MongoDB in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a document in MongoDB which holds the reference to other two documents. I have the get rest API which returns the object with details of that referencing document also. I have written the following code. The code is working but due to asynchronous reading feature the response that I am getting is empty.

```
router.get("/",function(req,res){

    LibraryTransaction.find({},function(err,data){

        if(err){
            res.send(err.message);
        }
        else{

            var transactions=[];
            data.forEach(function(element){                                 
                debugger;
                var transaction ={}; 
                var BookName='';
                var ISBNNumber='';
                var UserName='';

                

                Book.findOne({_id:element.book},function(err,book){
                    debugger;

                    if(!book){
                        res.send("Book not found please check ISBN number.");
                    }
                    else{           

                        BookName = book.name;
                        ISBNNumber= book.isbnNumber;
                        User.findOne({_id:element.user},function(err,user){
                            debugger;
                            if(!user){
                                res.send("User not found.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                UserName=user.userName;
                                transaction.bookName=BookName;
                                transaction.iSBNNumber=ISBNNumber;
                                transaction.userName=user.userName;
                                transaction.IssueDate=element.issueDate;
                                transaction.DueDate=element.dueDate;
                                transaction.TransactionType=element.transactionType;    
                                console.log(BookName);;
                                transactions.push(transaction);
                            }
                        });         
                    }
                });                 
            });
            console.log("Send");
            res.send(transactions);         
        }
    });
});
```

I have a transaction document which holds reference of Book and User document and some other details like bookIssueDate, DueDate etc. I want to return the data with book name, user name and Book issue Date, Book due date. But in response I am getting only Book issue date and Due date data but not the book name and user name. But the code reading that data form resopective document.

Can somebody help me understand the proper way to handle this in Node.js?

Comment: Wow, that's complete inefficient, do not ever do a query inside a for statement (in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick refactor in this case, map all ids into an array, and find all books with _id in that array, after that query you have all books and you can manipulate them. And obviously do a `res.send` or whatever you want in the call back.

```js
LibraryTransaction.find({},function(err,data){

    if(err){
        res.send(err.message);
    }
  
    else{

        var transactions=[];
        var bookIds = data.map(function(element) { return element.book; });
      
        Book.find({ _id: { $in: bookIds }}, function(err, books) {
          
          // Do whatever with books and send back the response, with res.. blah!
          
        });       
    }
});
```